# Merge First & Last name from database and display details in Text Field?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

First of all i'm sorry if this Question was asked already but I couldn't really find a solution to it.
So I'm trying to implement a program(using java & mysql) to ask user to enter a name in textfield then retrieve data from database and display details (setText on jtextfield). It works if i put first name only but don't know how to code to let user type first and last name in one text field and get data from database. The code i'm using that works with first name only as follows (Unfortunetly I'm not allowed to share any of my code):

```
//reads users input


String name = userName.getText();

//select data from 2 tables and display details based on user name


pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from table1, table2 where table1.fname=?");
pstmt.setString(1, name);
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Would appreciate if anyone can reply me with a solution. Thanks.

Comment: From the terse information provided, your database has a separate column for first and last names. If you need to read it in as one string, then you will need to look up Java string processing functions and split out first from last (delimited by space, perhaps, as long as you don't have "Jr", etc).

Comment: Why do you put last and first name in the same jTextField. It will be more easy if you use different ones.

Comment: Thank you for the kind replies. I got the solution using the split. I'm aware that using 2 text field was a better option but the program is being designed to use one text field. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use split (if the name and last name are two words)
but is better to use **two text field**

```
String name = userName.getText();
String[] names= name.split(" ");

pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from table1, table2 where table1.fname=? and table1.lname=?");
pstmt.setString(1, names[0]);
pstmt.setString(2, names[1]);
 rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just what i wanted. And ik I could've used 2 text field but the programs GUI & functionality was aim to use one textfield.  Using 2 text field was my 2nd option. But thanks :)